# 2013 nexus 7 usb help

Tags: rooting

My Nexus 7 all of a sudden stopped sending data through usb OTG and i tried to erase cache through TRWP but ended up deleting the OS. Now I am stuck with a device with no OS. I cannot mount the USB for my computer to recognise it so that I can restore it. I tried ADB sideload but it doesnt load and gets stuck on starting...

If I click on Mount, I cannot click on the USB-OTG box. My computer does have the correct drivers for the USB as it used to work on it before but since the OTG stopped responding to data I am now stuck and cannot push a restore image to the device.  I tried different OTG cables, different computers. None of the computers even detect a device as plugged in. Whether I boot into bootloader or recovery I just cannot get the PC to even acknowledge the fact that something is plugged in. As a result I am just not able to flash it at all. I tried NRT with the soft-brick option but that fails too because it says no adb connectivity.

Any help would really be appreciated.

I found this issue and have the same problem is there anyone that can help?

Comment: USB-OTG (see [tag:usb-on-the-go]) is a system for letting your phone be the "master" when you plug a USB peripheral into it. It's nothing to do with connecting to your PC. It's very confusing to try to understand what you're trying to connect to what, so please [edit] your question and try to describe the steps you've taken in clearer terms.

Comment: ADB requires a running system on the other end. If I understood correctly, you've wiped `/system`, so there's no OS to boot up. Unless you've got a custom recovery supporting it, there won't be any ADB server running there either – so no ADB (note: AFAIK TWRP supports it, you might have to enable it explicitly there). What's left to check is boot to bootloader and try accessing via [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info). If that works, you might be able to side-load a custom recovery or even directly install a ROM.

Comment: Try this link .... Worked for me https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#instructions